# Remove caching completely in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, caching, ionic-framework

I have an app that reads the latest posts from my Wordpress website and displays it in a list. The problem is every time the user reopens the app it loads an old (cached) list of articles even though there are new posts on my website.

I've been through it all in terms of disabling caching in ionic:

I've set `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`

My template's first line is this: `<ion-view class="home-view" cache-view="false">`

Tried setting `cache: false` in `.state('app.home')`

Tried loading a state like this: `$state.go('app.home', {}, {reload : true});` Did not work as expected.

Tried clearing the cache like this on resume: `$ionicHistory.clearHistory(); $ionicHistory.clearCache();`

Even tried stuff like `$route.reload` and `$window.location.reload` on resume but it's not working.

None of them work. I'm at the end of my rope here!

Please help!

Comment: this should not happen unless you fetch data from  localStorage or sqlite. Besides you can inspect the hybrid app by connecting it to your system and see if it really gets the desired response from your site.

Comment: I think it has more to do with Cordova and the phone than with Angular

Comment: You mean the phone is caching it, not the app?

Comment: @Ako, no... the app - but not the Angular part of it. From what you are describing, you are relaunching the app and it just shows you the same view, right? It seems like the app is resumed rather than restarted.

Comment: But even if I do $ionicHistory.clearHistory(); $ionicHistory.clearCache(); on resume, it gives me the old list.

Comment: why not just add a pull to refresh, I pull to refresh 9gag and flipboard like this when I just leave the app running in the background. Or give the app a JWT webtoken that times out, then when they try to use the app check if the webtoken still active every so often and if it isnt refresh data and give a new token.

Comment: There already is a pull to refresh feature but let's say my users get a push notification that there's a new post, they launch the app and don't see it but again see the old list. That's not acceptable. They shouldn't have to be pulling down to refresh there.

But anyway what I did was load the pull to refresh function's on beforeEnter like this:

`$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function() {
    $scope.doRefresh();
  });`

You never know, it might help someone else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I finally ended up doing was to load the pull to refresh's function on beforeEnter like this:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    $scope.doRefresh();
});
```

You never know, it might help someone else who finds themselves in the same situation as me :)

Comment: This can't be the answer.